# How is data transferred in an ajax GET call?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, request

Forgive me if this is a stupid quesiton but I fell upon an ajax call of type GET that for some reason passed some data along with it. And I thought to myself, who passes data along with a GET request?

```
$.ajax({
     url: "https://example/api/jobFinished/",
     dataType: "JSONP",
     type: "GET",
     jsonpCallback: "callback",
     data: {
         id: '1852',
         scid: '1952',
         cid: '120125'     
     },
```

**How is data transferred in an ajax GET request?**

secondary question: Why would anyone choose to transfer data with an ajax GET request as opposed to an ajax requets of type POST?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Logically, if you want to GET something from a server, you need to tell it WHAT you want to get; and to do that, you have to pass some data to the server.

Comment: It _should_ pass them as query parameters (?id=1852&scid=1952...), as to why you might pass data with a GET is to stick to convention, if you want to _get_ something from a server it'd be silly to use something called POST

Comment: `data` on requests that don't support a body (like a GET request) are passed as query strings. It's just a convenience jQuery provides so you can use the same method template for all sorts of requests.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get

Answer (score 2):

> How is data transferred in an ajax GET request?

On the query string.  For example:

```
https://example/api/jobFinished/?id=1852&scid=1952&cid=120125
```

You can observe this in your browser's debugging tools by watching the requests and responses.

> Why would anyone choose to transfer data with an ajax GET request

If the server is expecting a GET and not a POST.  Conventions suggest that one uses GET when only querying and not modifying data.

Comment: So bascially that ajax func is basically just converting all the data into a query string and sending that?

Comment: @RyanCameron: Basically, ya.  A GET request has no body, only a request to a URL, so that would be where the data has to go.